# Creating and managing multiple connections in Redis Python

Tags: python, redis, connection-pooling

I am using Redis to store two databases : 0 and 1 via the [Redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py) client library. I would like to create two connections for each database. Currently, I am doing this :

```
>>> connection0 = redis.Connection(host = 'localhost', port = 6379, db = 0)
>>> connection1 = redis.Connection(host = 'localhost', port = 6379, db = 1)
>>> connection0.connect()
```

However, I don't seem to find a way to create a Redis object from the connection.

```
>>> store0 = redis.Redis(connection0)
>>> store0.info()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis-2.4.11-py2.7.egg/redis/client.py", line 341, in info
    return self.execute_command('INFO')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis-2.4.11-py2.7.egg/redis/client.py", line 278, in execute_command
    connection.send_command(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis-2.4.11-py2.7.egg/redis/connection.py", line 258, in send_command
    self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis-2.4.11-py2.7.egg/redis/connection.py", line 241, in send_packed_command
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis-2.4.11-py2.7.egg/redis/connection.py", line 187, in connect
    sock = self._connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis-2.4.11-py2.7.egg/redis/connection.py", line 198, in _connect
    sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.0/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Connection found
```

Am I making a rookie mistake here?

Comment: did you able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You really shouldn't create connections like that. Let me quote the redis-py documentation.

> Behind the scenes, redis-py uses a connection pool to manage
>   connections to a Redis server. By default, each Redis instance you
>   create will in turn create its own connection pool. You can override
>   this behavior and use an existing connection pool by passing an
>   already created connection pool instance to the connection_pool
>   argument of the Redis class. You may choose to do this in order to
>   implement client side sharding or have finer grain control of how
>   connections are managed.

```
>>> pool = redis.ConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
>>> r = redis.StrictRedis(connection_pool=pool)
```

You cannot specify a single connection to be used with the library. Each Redis instance will have its own connection pool. When execute_command() is called, it will pop a connection from a the pool(or open a new one) and use that connection. If you only want your client to have max one connection at a time, set max_connections to 1.