# Does Redis Cluster support connection pooling using Python API?

Tags: python-3.x, connection-pooling, redis-cluster

Does Redis Cluster support connection pooling using python api "rediscluster"?
I have searched but could not find an appropriate link.
Can someone share the code or the link if connection pooling is supported in the python api?

Thank You,
Sachin Vyas

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984870/creating-and-managing-multiple-connections-in-redis-python

Answer (score 0):

If you check [rediscluster's page](https://pypi.org/project/rediscluster/) on PyPI, you'll find this note:

> rediscluster-py is based on the awesome redis-py StrictRedis Api, thus the original api commands would work without problems within the context of a cluster of redis servers

So you can rely on [redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/master/README.rst)'s API for connection pooling:

```
pool = redis.ConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
r = redis.Redis(connection_pool=pool)
```

Comment: You can but redis-py does not calculate cluster slots so it's not usable

Comment: check this link this would solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984870/creating-and-managing-multiple-connections-in-redis-python